# Wpf tabcontrol trig with parameter

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I've a tabcontrol in wpf, I want to send a trigger to my viewmodel when the tab selection changes. The trig should include either the tab name or the tab index.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=TabChangedCommand}"
                               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TabControl, Path=Name}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The trigger works fine, but the parameter is always null.

Comment: Share the code of your TabControl

Comment: Post XAML for full TabControl and ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing ElementName in the CommandParameter.

```
    <TabControl x:Name="mytab">
     ....
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=TabChangedCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=mytab}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    ....
    </TabControl>
```

do something like this

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve what your are trying by using MVVM.

You would have two properties in your ViewModel, one property to hold a collection of all the available tabs and another property to hold the currently selected tab.

**ViewModel**

```
public ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel> Tabs { get; private set; }

public ITabViewModel SelectedTab
{
    get { return _selectedTab; }
    set
    {
        _selectedTab = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedTab);
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}" />
```

With the above set-up, the SelectedTab property in the ViewModel gets updated whenever tab switch happens in the View.

Alternatively, if you are just interested in the index of selected tab. Have a property in the ViewModel to hold selected tab Index and bind it to SelectedIndex property on the TabControl.

**ViewModel**

```
public int SelectedTabIndex
{
    get { return _selectedTabIndex; }
    set
    {
        _selectedTabIndex = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedTabIndex);
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}"  />
```